# After creating shapefile from db the geometry coordinate becomes reverse order

Tags: c#, shapefile, dotspatial

I have a database table named 'hitbgt'. There is a column name 'the_geom' contains the geometry value. Get the data from db table as datatable and create a shapefile based on it. The codes are given below..........

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DbHandeler dbHandelerObj = new DbHandeler();
        string query = "Select st_asBinary(the_geom) as geom, * from hitbgt";

        try
        {
            dt = dbHandelerObj.GetDataTable(query);

            IFeature feature = new Feature();
            FeatureSet fs = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Polygon);              

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (dc.ColumnName != "the_geom" && dc.ColumnName != "geom")
                {
                    fs.DataTable.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                Byte[] data = (Byte[])dr["geom"];

                WkbReader wkbReader = new WkbReader();
                IGeometry geometry = wkbReader.Read(data);

                feature = fs.AddFeature(geometry);

                feature.DataRow.BeginEdit();                    
                foreach (DataColumn dc in fs.DataTable.Columns)
                {
                    feature.DataRow[dc.ColumnName] = dr[dc.ColumnName];                       
                }
                feature.DataRow.EndEdit(); 
            }

            fs.SaveAs("F:\\Test_value\\hitbgt_test.shp", true);
            fs.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Everything work fine. But when I retrieve the geom data from shapefile, the polygon coordinate values show reverse clockwise as in database.

```
        IList<Coordinate> shapeCorList = null;
        IFeatureSet fb = FeatureSet.Open("F:\\Test_value\\hitbgt_test.shp");
        foreach (IFeature ff in fb.Features)
        {
            if (ff.DataRow["cadid"].ToString() == "12345")
            {
                shapeGeometry = ff.BasicGeometry as IGeometry;
                shapeCorList = shapeGeometry.Coordinates;     
            }
        }
```

Example: 
Db geometry:
"POLYGON((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),(20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))"
Shape Geometry:
"MULTIPOLYGON(((35 10,10 20,15 40,45 45,35 10),(20 30,30 20,35 35,20 30)))"

Anyone please help.........

I am bothering with this because it needs to compare something like.......

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["cadid"].ToString() == "12345")
            {
                dbGeometry = reader.Read((Byte[])dr["geom"]);
                dbCorList = dbGeometry.Coordinates;                    
            }
        }          
        foreach (IFeature ff in fb.Features)
        {
            if (ff.DataRow["cadid"].ToString() == "12345")
            {
                shapeGeometry = ff.BasicGeometry as IGeometry;
                shapeCorList = shapeGeometry.Coordinates;
            }
        }

        bool equal = dbCorList.SequenceEqual(shapeCorList);
```

Comment: Why does it matter?  If it still describes the shape correctly, does it matter whether its clockwise or counterclockwise?  Does it even matter what point is listed first if it forms a closed loop?

Comment: Also, if you want help on the database side, you'll have to explain more about what specific database you're using, and how exactly you've configured it.

Comment: Yes in both case it creates the same polygon. But if I want to compare the two shape(from db and shapefile) based on their coordinates then it returns false.
I am using postgresql database.

Comment: Do you give any suggestions? @Matt Johnson

Comment: Instead of comparing their WKT strings, can't you just compare them as objects?  IIRC, `IGeometry.Equals` shouldn't care about the sequencing.

Comment: Thanks it works correctly while comparing objects. Could you please tell me while importing this shapefile to the postgresql and make a query like ST_AsText(geom) then it shows Multipolygon instead of polygon. @ Matt Johnson

Comment: I have no idea about that.  [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing WKT strings, load each polygon into an object and compare objects instead.  `IGeometry.Equals` should not care about the sequencing.